# How to have Mail.app in Lion sort messages within a thread oldest to newest (like gmail)

Tags: mail.app, macos

In Mail.app on 10.7 Lion, When I select an email thread, it shows all the emails within that thread in the right-hand pane, with the newest message first. How can I change this to sort from oldest to newest (the way that gmail shows messages when you are viewing a thread)?

Answer (score 7):

Go to:

```
Preferences -> View Tab
```

Then uncheck the bottom item labelled *"Show most recent message at the
top"*